# Combining a list of ranges in python

Tags: python, range, concatenation

What is the easiest way to construct a list of consecutive integers in given ranges, like this?

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,  15,16,17,18,19,  56,57,58,59]
```

I know the start and end values of each group.
I tried this:

```
ranges = (  range(1,8),
            range(15,20),
            range(56,60)  )
Y = sum( [ list(x) for x in  ranges ] )
```

which works, but seems like a mouthful. And in terms of code legibility, the `sum()` is just confusing. In MATLAB it's just

```
Y = [ 1:7, 15:19, 56:59 ]
```

Is there an better way? Can use `numpy` if easier.

### Bonus question

Can anybody explain why it doesn't work if I use a generator for the `sum`?

```
Y = sum( (list(x) for x in ranges) )
```

> TypeError: unsupported operand types for +: 'int' and 'list'

Seems like it doesn't know the starting value should be `[]` rather than `0`!

Comment: `ranges = list(range(1, 8)) + list(range(...)) + ...`…?

Comment: @deceze Or `itertools.chain` if you don't want to materialize e.g. `range(1, 1e20)` into a list...

Comment: If you do it often enough that the syntax is cumbersome, create a helper function: `def r(a, b): return list(range(a, b))`…

Comment: BTW, *both* uses of `sum` are producing that error…!

Comment: The reason why `sum` doesn't work with lists or generators is because the default `start` argument is `0`, as described here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=sum#sum

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The matlab syntax has it's equivalent in [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) with [`numpy.r_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html):

```
import numpy as np

np.r_[1:7, 15:19, 56:59]
```

output: `array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6, 15, 16, 17, 18, 56, 57, 58])`

For a list:

```
np.r_[1:7, 15:19, 56:59].tolist()
```

output: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 15, 16, 17, 18, 56, 57, 58]`

Answer (score 4):

One option, and maybe the closest to the Matlab syntax, is to use the star operator:

```py
>>> [*range(1,8), *range(15,20), *range(56, 60)]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 56, 57, 58, 59]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could you use itertool's [chain.from_iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable), which lazily evaluates the args from a single interable:

```
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable((range(1,8), range(15,20), range(56,60))))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 56, 57, 58, 59]
```

Answer (score 2):

To fix your code with `sum`, you can specify an empty list as the `start` keyword argument as the starting point of aggregation:

```
sum((list(x) for x in ranges), start=[])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own generator helper function:

```
def ranges(*argses):
    for args in argses:
        yield from range(*args)


for x in ranges((1, 7), (15, 19), (56, 59)):
    print(x)
```

If you need an actual list out of those multi-ranges, then `list(ranges(...))`.

Comment: *"My preccciouusssss argses…"* ;-)